# Program not accepting other file names on second pass

Tags: c++

I want to program an input validation loop that makes sure the user inputs in a valid file name but for some reason, it works the first time but after the second time, it doesn't take any file names at all. Here's what I have so far:

```
// header files here
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    const int TOTAL_SIZE = 100;

    float arr[TOTAL_SIZE];

    int numCount = 0;

    string fileName;

    ifstream inputFile;

    while (true)
    {
        // Asks for an input file name
        cout << "Input a file name. Input a \"*\" to quit: ";
        cin >> fileName;

        // Checks for sentinel value
        if (fileName == "*")
            return 0;

        // Opens the file
        inputFile.open(fileName);

        // Makes sure the file can be openned, if not ask the user again
        while (!(inputFile))
        {
            // Output the error message
            cout << "You have entered an invalid file name. Please try again: ";

            // Clear the error and ignore the bad input
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

            // Let the user try again
            cin >> fileName;

            // Make sure its not the sentinel value
            if (fileName == "*")
                return 0;

            // Attempt to open the file again
            inputFile.open(fileName);

        }

        numCount = insertionSort(inputFile, arr, numCount);

        printArr(arr, numCount);

    }



    return 0;
} // ends main()
// Does stuff after
```

And this is what it outputs. File c.txt is one file and t.txt is another different file I have to sort. I can try one or the other first but then it won't open the second one after the task is done

```
Input a file name. Input a "*" to quit: c.txt
** Good Output ** 
Input a file name. Input a "*" to quit: t.txt
You have entered an invalid file name. Please try again: t.xtx
You have entered an invalid file name. Please try again: t.txt
You have entered an invalid file name. Please try again: c.txt
You have entered an invalid file name. Please try again:
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't compare strings with ==. Research comparing strings in C/C++

Comment: @nicomp You can use `==` if it is a `std::string`.  (Can't tell from this example.)

Comment: If `inputFile` is broken, why are you clearing and ignoring `cin`?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @0x5453 Good point. Hopefully OP will provide clarity on that.

Comment: are you closing the `inputFile` stream after the first successful opening?

Comment: @nicomp I've updated it with more code I hope that helps. I didn't realize we couldn't do that with c++. I've done that multiple times and my professors seem to be happy with it so I thought it was fine. That's mb

Comment: @Waqar Actually you're right. I forgot to close my file after doing stuff with it. Thanks a ton.